# Understanding Deep vs Shallow Copy in Python 2.x

Tags: python-2.x, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I was looking online and I came across these 3 segments of code. The question is to predict the output and explain why.

Example 1:

```
x = 42
y = x
x = x + 1
print x
print y
```

Output Example 1:

```
43
42
```

Example 2:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
x[0] = 4
print x
print y
```

Output Example 2:

```
[4, 2, 3]
[4, 2, 3]
```

Example 3:

```
x = ['foo', [1,2,3], 10.4]
y = list(x) # or x[:]
y[0] = 'fooooooo'
y[1][0] = 4
print x
print y
```

Output Example 3:

```
['foo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
['fooooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
```

For the most part I understand that this is a question about shallow and deep copying but I can't seem to wrap my head around this simple thing. In Example 2 at `x[0] = 4` I understand that `x` and `y` are pointing to the same object and therefore both `x` and `y` are redefined and not just `x` in this statement. But then why in Example 3 does this same logic not follow. At `y[0] = 'fooooooo'` this should cause `x` and `y` to be redefined, just like the following line at `y[1][0] = 4` causes both `x` and `y` to be redefined together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so we can dissect this a bit more:

```html
>>> x = ['foo', [1,2,3], 10.4]
>>> y = list(x) # or x[:]
>>> z=x
>>> id(x)
4354889544
>>> id(y)
4354890184
>>> id(z)
4354889544
```

```html
>>> y[0] = 'fooooooo'
>>> y[1][0] = 4
>>> y
['fooooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
>>> x
['foo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
>>> id(x[1])
4354889672
>>> id(y[1])
4354889672
```

See it now? When you use the function `List()` it is creating a new object in a new memory location... but to save space python will keep the same pointer to the mutable internal objects, like the list. [This](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) article can explain more what is mutable and what is not.

Comment: If `y` is a new object `list()` then why would `y[1][0]` point back to a shared list and not `y`'s own value?

Comment: Python tries to limit the new memory space so the new list just still holds a shared pointer with the original list for that mutable object.`y[1] -> mem <- x[1]`